# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

WordPress Development's [fourth moderator election](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: gmazzap] [image: Howdy_McGee]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/6283024819814400/0).

Answer (score 11):

Congratulations to our new moderators! And *thank you* to the other candidates.

Answer (score 7):

Thumbs up for Howdy and Gmazzap! Good luck with your new job. Christine, Gabriel and Joshua, thumbs up for you too. There will still be plenty of work left for everybody :-)

Answer (score 6):

Gratulations to the new colleagues! Great to see two experienced people getting their hands dirty and help. Thanks to all participating candidates!

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations to our new moderators for their efforts to keep going this great community. many thanks to ***all*** the great team!